# VSTO Mock Range and add data from query to mocked range

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, moq

I haven’t written anything concrete yet, but I have a VSTO application and I would like to do the following:

1) Mock a Range Interop using Moq

2) Add a querytable to the mocked range so that it’s populated with the data returned from a SQL query

3) Add a DataValidation to a cell (range) from my current worksheet using the mocked range’s data as a List of possible itens within the combobox drop down.

Is this behavior possible at all?

In my first attempt I was able to create the mocked range but my ListObject would not be created using a mocked range instead of an actual range.

Any tips would be appreciated

As requested, here's some code:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
values.Add("First");
values.Add("Second");
if(values.Count > 0)
{
    string data = String.Join(";", values);
    var mockedrange = new Mock<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range>();
    for(int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
    {
        mockedrange.Setup(r => r[i, It.IsAny<object>()]).Returns(values[i]);
    }

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range3 = VSTOSheet.Cells[countaux, 3];
    range3.Select();
    range3.Validation.Delete();
    range3.Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList,
                          XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation,
                          XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, 
                          data, 
                          Type.Missing);
    range3.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
    range3.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: I edited the question with something like what I intend to do. Basically, I want to use a formula to the mocked range instead of the data within the Validation.Add() method.

Comment: Thanks for anyone trying to figure this out. At the moment, I solved the problem creating a table connected to the database in a far column of my Excel sheet, hidding the table’s column and then pointing my validation to this range. This way I can add a validation list with the data returned from my query without using Moq or a List<string> of the data which was limited to 1000 records.